# adding validation cause error 1004 in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I define some names in name manger like **validation_list1** that refers to **=OFFSET(Sheet3!$C$4,,,COUNTIF(Sheet3!$C$4:$C$399,"?*"))**

I want to add validation list using vba . code below cause error 1004:

```
With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="=validation_list1"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = False
    ' Code with error
End With
```

but when I delete equal sign (**=**) from the text assigned to Formula1 every thing will be ok

```
With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="validation_list1"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = False
    'code without error!
End With
```

both above codes are similar but first one has *Formula1:="=validation_list1"* and second one has *Formula1:="validation_list1"* . why first one cause error 1004? I have to add *Formula1:="=validation_list1"* , how?

I do not have any problem with defining name manager , the problem is adding equal sign between quotation marks (the text assigned to Formula1 ). It does not matter what is the text , I tested it by **Formula1:="=test"** and caused error too then deleted = sign and wrote **Formula1:="test"** and everything were good.

***Edit:*** Thanks chris neilsen . this piece of code is the output of *Record Macro* and if I manually select a cell and from `Data` tab and select `Data Validation` and enter the text **=validation_list1** in `Source` field of list validation , everything will be ok but using vba causes error

***SOLVED***
Thank you very much @chrisneilsen , your advices helped me to find the reason. Individually every things seem to be ok .formula , scope and named range were correct . This validation occurs after the program does some calculations and changes to sheets and formulas , so one cell which indirectly related to validation change to #REF . I used **Define Name** for formula of that cell and BINGO

Comment: @farid Help me to help you.  Did you check the things I mentioned?  As I said, it works for me.  There must be something else about your workbook you haven't told us

Comment: @chrisneilsen Yes I checked all of them. I do not know what else about my workbook might exist

Comment: @farid what result did you get when you typed `=validation_list1` in a cell?

Answer (score 0):

As you know, you must include the `=` in the Formula1 assignment.  If you don't then you are assigning a literal string, not a named range.

When you assign the Formula1 value, this error will occur if:

- The named range doesn't exist (as happens when you tried `Formula1:="=test"`), or
- The named range is Worksheet scoped, and you try to use it in Validation on a different sheet
- The named range exists but its "RefersTo" is not valid

I tried you setup, named range and code.  It worked for me, using Excel 365

```vb
Sub test()
    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=validation_list1"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Name definition
[image]

Validation List data
[image]

After running code with `B4:B5` selected
[image]

Proof that Named range works
[image]

Things to check

- Check `validation_list1` is Workbook scoped
- The data in `Sheet3!C4:C399` is valid (no errors, no gaps)
- there are no typos in the named range name or formula
- type `=validation_list1` in a cell.  What do you see?